# Change Default UpdateSourceTrigegr value for all TextBox's in Silverlight

Tags: .net, binding, textbox, silverlight-5.0, updatesourcetrigger

We have a custom TextBox (inherits TextBox) and we would like to change the TextProperty's Binding's UpdateSourceTrigger value to Explicit. In Silverlight, there are only three values which are Default, Explicit and PropertyChanged.

Is there any common way to do it from within the Control's code?

Comment: Any snippet or link to guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
I was experimenting with this:

```
    private void CustomTextBox1_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            var b = tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            var p = b.ParentBinding;
            p.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;  /* ERROR */

        }
    }
```

On the line marked 'ERROR' an exception was thrown: `Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.`  I don't know how you could get to the Text property's Binding any earlier.
What's wrong with setting it in xaml?